# Android camera API 2 can't open video after saving

Tags: android, video, camera

I am using camera video API 2 from google samples [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video). All goes right and when I wont check the movie I got an error **"Failed to play video, An unknown error has occurred."** This bug happens on samsung s7 and nexsus 5x. Where is the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: First of all, download the video samples to your PC and try to open them with, e.g. **ffmpeg**. Enable debug output, and analyze, what goes wrong.

Comment: That is google sample. how it cannot save the video? BTW didn't find solution in ffmpeg

Comment: I'm missing something. You saved a video file on your device. You cannot play it on the device. Can you play it elsewhere? Which *solution* didn't you find in ffmpeg??

Comment: I also downloaded VLC player app and MX Player and it cannot open the mp4 file

Comment: can you post the code about how are u saving the video in your app?